# Need help understanding OWASP Vulnerabilities

Tags: xss, sql-injection, csrf, owasp, owasp-top-ten

I am doing a whitepaper on simplifying OWASP 10 vulnerabilities based on an article our teachers suggested. Can you guys help or provide more resources here? What are your views? Will like to interview some of you for the study too.

Comment: I suggest you built a google forms form with the interview questions and then post it on forums asking people to fill out the form for your reasearch

Comment: Asking for external resources are off topic, unfortunately. If you need interview participants, you could try asking in [chat].

Comment: This is really, really broad. You also don't say how you have tried to approach the problem, which makes it seem like you want us to do your homework. Please narrow your question and provide your own thoughts to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well It's not about OWASP Top 10 / Top 20 / Top n, those can be changed over time (xss is more present right now then it was back in 90'), what actually matters at OWASP is there update to the technology methodologies (v.1 v.2 .. v.4) that offer an exhaustive testing plan of a Web based application. If you want to simplify them ... you should take in account that the next day, week, month, year it will be another Top 10. The scope of those top's is not to be simple understandable it's serve as a snapshot in time of the most common vulnerability. And I can have an web based app that is not vulnerable to OWASP Top 10 at all but it fails dramatically on other sides.

Answer (score 0):

As this feels as a school-assignment, I would  recommend buying one or two of the "basic" web security books which often discusses all of the most popular vulnerabilities. This will make you understand the vulnerabilities better and therefore you can explain them in any way you feel like in the paper.

As for the interview part the google form idea presented by Bubble Hacker seems like a good start.